Is there a way to summarize individual totals under one category?
I am supposed to create an SQL query that determines the total hours of certain projects from two tables, totals them per month and lists them.
I've got these tables:
Table "A"



ID
Name




1
Alpha


2
Beta


3
Gamma


4
Delta



Table "B"



ID
Hours
Date




1
10
2020-01-15


2
30
2020-01-03


1
10
2020-01-12


4
5
2020-03-02



I've got tried this:
SELECT A.Name, B.Hours, B.Date
FROM A INNER JOIN B ON A.ID = B.ID
WHERE A.Name Like 'Alpha' OR A.Name Like 'Beta' OR A.Name Like 'Gamma' 

which results in:



Name
Hours
Date




Alpha
10
2020-01-15


Alpha
10
2020-01-12



But I need something like this:



Year, Month
Name
Hours




2020-01
Alpha
20


2020-01
Beta
30


2020-01
Gamma
0


2020-02
Alpha
...and so on



I would be very grateful if you could help me here.

Use a calendar table.

Try format(B.Date,'yyyy-MM') and using group by this and the name, with a sum of hours

@Nathan_Sav Thank you, this helped.  Now I've got this:
SELECT Format(B.Date, 'yyyy-MM') as Date, A.Name, SUM(B.Hours) as T
FROM A INNER JOIN Leistung ON A.ID = B.ID
WHERE A.Name Like 'Alpha' OR A.Name Like 'Beta' OR A.Name Like 'Gamma' GROUP BY Date, A.Name;
Dont know why my question was closed. The linked one does not helped me... I think its because of guys with anime avatars.

Google GROUP BY SQL that will help.  Also ditch the likes, just use = as you have no wildcards, also look at using IN too.
